# How to authomatize re-install process of slack app?

Tags: scope, slack-api

I'am developing a slack bot. Bot app should work with files, which are added by slack users in my worspace. In order to obtain access to users's files, bot app needs to get permission scope of specific user, as described in article: https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack.

Everything works fine. Users press allow button and grant necessary permission to a bot. But there is an issue: every time slack app needs to be re-installed to save the changes. "You’ve changed the permission scopes your app uses. Please reinstall your app for these changes to take effect (and if your app is listed in the Slack App Directory, you’ll need to resubmit it as well)."

Manual re-install process is not a handy way, because i got many users in workspace. Users can give permissions to a bot in random time. Is there an automatic way to reinstall app?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, there is no automated way to reinstall the app. I'd recommend a check perhaps that prompts the user to follow a "reinstall" link if you get the missing scopes error back

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it isn't bad idea to add special api request to re-install app in case app is asking for it.